# Using a Raspberry Pi from another network

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

The idea to be able to connect to my raspberry pi via SSH when I am not a home. How do I do this? Do I just port-forward it? I also want to connect to it from my domain (polardragon.cf) instead of my IP address. What is the easiest way to do this? If i need to, I can access the GUI.

My internet ip is static, I have an ip per device, NAT is enabled (I can turn it off if needed).

Comment: You will have to answer the following questions: Do you have a static IP address? Do you have an IP per device? Do you have a publicly rotatable IP address? or are you behind a nat?, if so what type of nat? To get us started type `/sbin/ifconfig` and the result to the question.

Comment: And by static IP address, we refer to your internet IP, not the Pi’s internal IP.

Comment: OK. does what I have so far work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with or without a dynamic IP using a service such as DynDNS which links your dynamic IP address to a domain name. Just set this up and choose a name and a port then just use port translation (or forwarding) on your router to access the raspberry - for example if you want to access via HTTP, you could choose a port and redirect it to port 80 on the raspberry. Note to make this work well, you would need to set a static address on the raspberry on your local network.  For example.

get a DynDNS account and domain (or a similar service) - say www.name1.name2.org
Choose a port (say 5000)
On the router, forward inward port request 5000 to your raspberry port 80 so to access the raspberry, you'd call www.name1.name2.org:5000 and that would redirect to 192.168.0.xx:80 (your home network address for the raspberry).